# transformation from xml document to relational model with t-sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

I need to insert into table data from xml docs (in relational model) that i have in other table. I'm using sql server 2005.

example of structure of xml:

```
<order id=”123”>
<products>
    <product prodId=”2120”>
        <name>Product1</name>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </product>
    <product prodId=”1200”>
        <name>Product2</name>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
    </product>
    <product prodId=”945”>
        <name>Product3</name>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </product>
</products>
</order>
```

... and result table:

```
OrderID  ProductID  Name      Quantity
123      2120       Product1  2
123      1200       Product2  4
123      945        Product3  1
```

I solve this problem with openxml tool but it's bit slow.
How can i do this in XQuery?
What is the best metod to solve tasks like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "open xml tool"? Is it [this OPENXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx)? If so, please add the code you have for solving this with openxml. Without it, it is impossible to provide an answer that will execute faster.

Comment: As far as I know `openxml` is much faster than xquery for shredding large chunks of xml data. So, you're already using the best method available.

Comment: Anyways, google `xml shredding sql-server`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xml_str XML =  
   '<order id="123"> <products>
    <product prodId="2120">
        <name>Product1</name>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </product>
    <product prodId="1200">
        <name>Product2</name>
        <quantity>4</quantity>
    </product>
    <product prodId="945">
        <name>Product3</name>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </product> </products> </order>'

SELECT  
    c.value('(../../@id)', 'int') AS OrderID, 
    c.value('(@prodId)[1]', 'int') AS ProductID,
    c.value('(./name)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS Name,
    c.value('(./quantity)[1]', 'int') AS Quantity
FROM @xml_str.nodes ('(/order/products/product)') AS t(c)
GO

OrderID     ProductID   Name                 Quantity
----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------
123         2120        Product1             2
123         1200        Product2             4
123         945         Product3             1

(3 row(s) affected)
```